# Application of Bayes theorem and Partition Law, total probability

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

[image]

Hi guys, preparing for my finals and trying to get this question out for practice. The exam is in a couple of hours so apologies for being brief.

I think I have computed parts 1 and 2 fine.

$$0.3*0.1 + 0.7*0.3 = 0.24$$

for the first part, and

$$P(\text{parasite} \mid A) = \frac{P(A \mid \text{parasite})P(\text{parasite})}{P(A)}$$

$$= \frac{0.7*0.3}{0.3*0.7 + 0.7*0.2} = 0.6$$

Hopefully these parts are both correct so far.

Now for part iii), I started out 
$$P(A_2 \mid A_1) = \frac{P(A_1 \mid A_2)P(A_2)}{P(A_1)}$$
but this doesn't really make any sense. So then I tried

$$P(A_2 \mid A_1)= P(A_2 \mid A_1, \text{parasite}) +  P(A_2 \mid A_1, \text{no parasite}) $$

I'm not sure where to go with it after this or if that approach is correct at all. I know I ought to look for a hint and then work through the rest myself but as the exam is so soon I would really appreciate someone pointing out the next couple of steps, and maybe even a hint/setup for part iv).

Comment: (iii) is just $p(A_2\cap \text{parasite})+p(A_2\cap \text{no parasite})=0.7\times0.6+0.2\times0.4=0.5$. For (iv) use the same idea as before.

Comment: OK, I think that's pretty much just computing what I had set up, but I didn't see that at the time, thanks. I'm still struggling to get an intuition for how to set up iv), can you walk me through the logic? I think this could be important.

Comment: Write $b$ for parasite, we have $p(b|A_2)=\frac{p(A_2|)p(b)}{p(A_2)|b)p(b)+p(A_2|\text{not }b)p(\text{not }b)}$. So just as before, except that we have now updated $p(b)$ and $p(\text{not }b)$ in the light of the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is the right idea, but what you were after is:

$$\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1) ~=~ \mathsf P(A_2\mid P_{\rm arasite})~\mathsf P(P_{\rm arasite}\mid A_1)+\mathsf P(A_2\mid P_{\rm arasite}^\complement)~\mathsf P(P_{\rm arasite}^\complement\mid A_1)$$

---

Now you are looking for $\mathsf P(P_{\rm arasite}\mid A_1,A_2)$ using Bayes' Rule, and the fact that the events of the two butterflies both being type A are conditionally independent given the presence/absence of the parasite.

Comment: $\mathsf P(P_{\rm arasite}\mid A_1,A_2) = \frac{\mathsf P(A_1, A_2\mid P_{\rm arasite}) * P_{\rm arasite}}{P(A_1, A_2 \mid P_{\rm arasite})*P(A_1, A_2 \mid P^c_{\rm arasite})}$
Is this along the right lines for setting up part iv)?

Comment: Close; the denominator is simply $\mathsf P(A_1,A_2)$. $\dfrac{\mathsf P(A_1,A_2\mid P_{\rm arasite})~\mathsf P(P_{\rm arasite})}{\mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)}$